# How to turn on an infrared vision in Crysis 2 Demo?

Tags: crysis-2

I often see other players kill me with infrared vision turned on(they see other players in blue, red colors). How can I turn it on too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the 'i' key?  In the first Crysis, it was the key to turn night vision on and off.

Or are you referring to the 'nanovision'?  Press the 'N' key to toggle it on or off.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is really called nanovision. However the default key for it is 'N' in Crysis 2. Please correct your answer and I will accept it.